# git file shows in commit, but when trying to show it says it doesn't exist

Tags: git

This is my output for git show commit:

```
$git show --pretty="format:" --name-only e129a7d5416f8773dc1b379644a5157a1286ac

modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/config/managed/AnnotationServiceInterceptor.java
modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/config/managed/ManagedServiceInterceptor.java
modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/config/service/ManagedService.java
modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/cpr/AsynchronousProcessor.java
modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/cpr/DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java
modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/cpr/FrameworkConfig.java
modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/handler/ReflectorServletProcessor.java
modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/websocket/DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java
```

however, when I try to show **modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/config/managed/ManagedServiceInterceptor.java** (and only that file), I get the error that it is not in the commit:

```
$git show e129a7d5416f8773dc1b379644a5157a1286ac3b:modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/config/managed/ManagedServiceInterceptor.java
fatal: Path '/modules/cpr/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/config/managed/ManagedServiceInterceptor.java' not exist in 'e129a7d5416f8773dc1b379644a5157a1286ac3b'
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file is removed in a commit, it will be listed in the `git show --name-only` output.  Perhaps that file was removed by the commit in question.

Comment: Is there anyway to filter those files out before hand? an alternative to git show perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

error is saying that file is missing in commit e129a7d5416f8773dc1b379644a5157a1286ac3b and you are listing e129a7d5416f8773dc1b379644a5157a1286ac

those are two different commit hashes.

Comment: A. It's the same commit hash, one is just missing 2 letters and git knows how to add those on its own.
B. It's just a paste mistake, I fixed it (I searched for 3b in both)